# Get the data of specific user in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, authentication

Now I have created a login form with a session, what I need now that when the user login with his username and password, get his data such as name, about etc.. and put it in the welcome page.

Currently I have created this code but this code get all users data,

```
 <?php 
 mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("usersdata") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userid") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 Print "<table border cellpadding=3>"; 
 while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
 { 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Name:</th> <td>".$info['Name'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Username:</th> <td>".$info['Email'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 } 
 Print "</table>"; 
 ?>
```

I hope to find a way to do that. :D

Comment: what is your problem? do the tables even contain the userdata?

Comment: Is your database users table really called "userid"?  Do they contain both the "Name" and "Email" columns?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM userid WHERE username = ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already created a login form with session then you get the data for the current logged in user by doing this:

`$_SESSION['userid']`: Should be filled in the login page.
`$_SESSION['userid'] = $id`

Learn more about the sessions: [PHP Sessions W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

And then:

```
$query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `userid` WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['userid']."' ")or die(mysql_error());
$arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($query); //this will count the rows (if exists)
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
 //...
<?php if($num > 0){ ?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3">
<tr><td colspan="2" align="center">Your Info</td></tr>
<tr>
 <td>Name: <?php echo $arr['Name']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>Email: <?php echo $arr['Email']; ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php }else{ ?>
 User not found.
<?php } ?>
 //...
</html>
```

Comment: Your welcome and I also suggest to rename the table to `users` and all the columns name to lower letter `email` instead of `Email`.

Read more about about it [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22947/A-Naming-Scheme-for-Database-Tables-and-Fields)

Answer (score 1):

Although you should use the mysqli_ extension, rather than mysql_, you would want something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userid WHERE username = '" . $username . "'")
    or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
    //Found the user
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    //Results can be accessed like $row['username'] and $row['Email']
} else {
    //Too few or too many records were found
}
```

Note: I've used username='$username' as an example. It would be best to track the user's ID from the login process as the ID refers to a specific row.

Comment: Thank you Jacob for trying to help me; your help was useful Best Regards Ahmed Fathi

Answer (score 0):

Your example code retrieves all users from the database and loops through the data using a `while` loop.

To get the user that has logged in you need to change your query that fetches the data.
I'm assuming you have a primary key in your table and know the id because the user already logged in.

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userid WHERE id={$userid}");
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
echo $info['Name'];
```

`$info` will now contain all the user info for 1 user, you need to fill `$userid` with the actual id from the user that is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

> `$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userid")`

Should be

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM userid WHERE Name='$selectedName'")
```

Of course you need to define `$selectedName`

I also recommend you read http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html to learn about some fundamentals.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, Thanks , Best Wishes Ahmed Fathi